# tf.reduce_sum returning larger than expected value

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to code up a Neural Network that takes input features and return an output. However I would like to check the "correctness" of the NN by comparing the output to the real output. At the same time, I would like to allow this metric to account for a uncertainty in the output. Let's say if the predicted output is within 1 unit away from the real output, count that predicted output as correct.

**Code intent**: Check if |x-y| is less than or equal to 1 , if so count up all the occurrence where this is true. Essentially so I can know how many cases are true.

Here's the code below,

```
correct = tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(tf.less_equal(tf.abs(x - y), 1), tf.int32))
correct.eval({x: predicted_output, y = real_output})
```

When I pass a small list to the dictionary (code below), I can get back correct results:

```
{x: [1,2,3,4,5], y: [1,2,3,1,1,]}
```

However when I pass the **predicted output** and **real output** which is of **length 10 000**, sometimes the return value is **more than** 10 000.

Am I correct in assuming that the returned value must be less than 10 000? If yes, than what mistakes am I making that would cause the return value to be more than 10 000?

EDITED to include full-ish code:

```
def neural_network_model(data):
 hidden_1_layer = {"weights": tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input, n_nodes_hl1])),
                  "biases": tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1]))}
 hidden_2_layer = {"weights": tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1, n_nodes_hl2])),
                  "biases": tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2]))}
 hidden_3_layer = {"weights": tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2, n_nodes_hl3])),
                  "biases": tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl3]))}
 output_layer = {"weights": tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl3, n_output])),
                  "biases": tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_output]))}

 l1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data, hidden_1_layer["weights"]), hidden_1_layer["biases"])
 l1 = tf.nn.relu(l1)

 l2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l1, hidden_2_layer["weights"]), hidden_2_layer["biases"])
 l2 = tf.nn.relu(l2)

 l3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l2, hidden_3_layer["weights"]), hidden_3_layer["biases"])
 l3 = tf.nn.relu(l3)

 output = tf.matmul(l3, output_layer["weights"]) + output_layer["biases"]

 return output

prediction = neural_network_model(x)
correct = tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(tf.less_equal(tf.abs(prediction - y), 1), tf.int32))
correct.eval({x: val_features, y: val_label})
```

Comment: Working fine for me with random integers. Could you please let me know number of classes you have ? is it 10000 ? Did you check  max and min values of x and y ?

Comment: @hars Number of classes is one. its a single continuous output NN. I've edited the question to include more information regarding the code.

not included in the edit, is running the training session. before checking correct.

Comment: Did you check the size of x,y and hat values it has when it does ?

Comment: with just the information above I best bet is that one of **val_features** or **val_labels** (or both) has more than 1 rank.

Comment: @hars whats the best way to check a tensor shape in tensorflow session? Im not used to this computation graph method that tf is using. The val_features is a 10000 x 12 array. And val_label is a 10000 long vector. Which should be the correct shape yes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the source of the error.

In this case val_label was taken from a larger numpy array called **data**. The label is located at last column of the **data** array.

```
val_label = data[:, -1]
```

this apparently returned an array with dimension (10 000, ) which is a vector

When this is compared to the tensor of val_labels which is of dimension (10 000, 1) the error occurred.

The fix was to ensure that val_label array was of dimension (10 000, 1) which is done like so:

```
val_label = data[:, -1:]
```

or:

```
val_label = data[:, -1]
val_label = val_label.reshape((-1,1))
```

Re-evaluating the tensorflow graph will then return the correct expected output